# Show scaling effect on hover inside overflow hidden parent

Tags: html, css, slider

I am using a content slider (thumbnail slider) when hovering on each element, I want to scale it (make it bigger) and the scaling is prevented by overflow hidden of the parent, basically its something like this

```
.parent {
  overflow hidden
}
.child:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Here is a codepen of the slider itself

http://codepen.io/nadeemkhedr/pen/OXkKxa?editors=1100

Comment: You should remove overflow: hidden. There is no way to make such effect with overflow container.

Comment: @3rdthemagical overflow hidden is required for the slider itself to hide the overflowed slides

Comment: I have bad news for you.

Comment: of course you could just change your design a bit.just add a bit of height to the container and some space between the elements so then you would be able to scale them

Comment: @GeorgePant I though of that, and it solved the top padding when zooming but the left padding for the first slide and right padding for the last one I still didn't figure it out

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXKbWw?editors=1100 If you just change the height of the parent divs it seems ok The only problem in the example is the last element that is cut in the middle But that has nothing to do with scaling it happens anyway If you could provide your full working code including js I would help you more

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly  you want your child element to be bigger than parent after scaling. If that is the case here is the JSfidlle with the solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/7vd6fhfo/3/

And the code:

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:green;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.child{
  width:190px;
  height:190px;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
}
.child:hover{ 
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Comment: But the parent has overflow: hidden.

Comment: Ok. Try to add some children. To set position absolute to child you must add position relative to parent. And this code doesn't work. It's impossible to show something outside container with overflow:hidden.

Comment: Its work because parent isn't relative. But if you add absolute children, you should set position to them. So container must be relative.

Comment: I posted the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7vd6fhfo/3/ If you remove position:absolute it doesn't work, if you put it back it works. Try it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118294/discussion-between-tezekiel-and-3rdthemagical).

Comment: @Tezekiel can you check my codepen example, problem is that you have multiple items side by side and want for each one on hover to do the effect

Comment: I understand the problem now. What is the stackoverflow policy, should I delete answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below code.

```css
.item { float:left; position: relative; border: 1px solid #333; 
  overflow: hidden; width: 350px;}
.item img {width: 100%; display:table-cell;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.item:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
  transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg/image" alt="image" width="100%" >
</div>
```

Hope you like it.

Comment: I want the img to extend outside of the container

Comment: then you can only remove the overflow: hidden from class .item